# Swift2 transparent navigation bar methods. –> pure black color

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, swift2, ios9

I have a issue with swift 2.0 and ios9. I can't completely make navigation bar transparent. I know there is a thread with this issue, but looks like i am the only one that is getting the black color of navBar.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/*
*   Make navigation bar transpadent.
*/
private func navBarSetup(hidden:Bool, trans:Bool){
    self.navigationController!.navigationBarHidden = hidden
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = trans
}
```

- make sure your nav bar in storyboard is enabled + check extend edges: Under top Bars